# Cross browser Fonts

Tags: fonts, cross-browser

I hate that Lucida Grande is not usable on Internet Explorer.  Why is that? And is Calibri a font that can be used on IE?

Comment: Calibri should indeed work in IE as long as it's installed.

Comment: Ask Jobs why Lucida Grande isn't an open font.

Answer (score 3):

If you're on a Macintosh, a lot of fonts are installed by default, including Lucida Grande. Windows doesn't install the same range as fonts as Mac OS X, so fonts like Lucida Grande are likely to be missing.

Calibri should be installed on Windows computers with Office >=2007 or 2003 with 2007 compatibility, and likewise for Mac with Office >=2008 or compatibility tools. You probably shouldn't rely on it however.

The [Wikipedia page for web typography](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_typography) has some information on what fonts should be available to use on most computers, and how to degrade gracefully if a font isn't present.

Answer (score 2):

different browsers simply support different font renderings.  there can be a multitude of reasons why but its not even worth pondering about, the fact is that this is just the case. Anyway the best defense against this is to define a font-family in css so that you have a fallback plan in case your first desired font is not available.  aside from that you can also follow this little trick [here](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/using-font-face/) if you want to force browsers to use a custom font, but just make sure you have rights to use the font before anything.

Comment: Yeah the problem is that i am using lucida grande for the menu options so now i have to find another font and reconfigure css.

Comment: i feel your pain on this.  toughest part about css is just staying as flexible as possible, especially since different browsers and different versions will always have their own take on how a page should look.